# Bug: Editing my own answer duplicates it

Tags: bug

I answered a question, but forgot to add a link to a reference, so I edited it to add it. I'm not too sure what happened, but it seems to have duplicated the answer, one with the 'correct' one, and the other with no links (there was one before) and no content in the blockquotes (although they are still blockquote blocks)

[Here's the question I'm talking about](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408628/adjective-that-means-control-freak/).

Is this a bug, or due to a break in connection with my phone? I have no idea how to reproduce it.

For purposes of working out what has happened, I'm using a phone browser (BlackBerry, don't ask why :P) on the website (mobile version) with WiFi but it's pretty knackered sometimes so I might have blipped connection when it was POSTing to the SE servers.

Comment: Depends. If it was on a mobile app, it is surely doomed from the start. And the SE devs have abandoned it sorta.

Comment: @NVZ nope, not app. I'm using the website (albeit the mobile version)

Comment: That's important info. Add it to the question.

Comment: Were you using multiple tabs? [This MSO bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280179/6083675) may be relevant.